# Casting to other class in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a code (simplified):

```
class A(object):
    attrib1 = "a"
    attrib2 = "b"

class B(A):
    flag = True
```

in some place in my code, I have an instance of A, but I need to create an instance of class B, which will have all the data from instance of A... I feel myself stupid, but I don't want to do something like:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,a1,a2,a3,a4,..):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2
```

and call like:

```
obj_b = B( obj_a.a1, obj_a.a2,...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.__dict__.update(obj.__dict__)
```

Comment: Note that this is generally a bad idea. Verify the type of `obj` and copy only the attributes that matter.

Comment: This will solve a problem for now, and I will solve a problem as soon as it will arise, but thanks for warning.

Comment: `__dict__` may not be available and it breaks if you use `property`... Also, some of the data may be defined in the class so, it will not be inside `obj.__dict__`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to change the `__class__` variable on your instance of A.

```
a = A()
a.__class__ = B
```